# How to run a Palm Pre App on desktop?

Tags: palm-pre

I really need (This is very important to me) to get on an Palm Pre app. The app does reqire Wifi. I am running Windows 7

Is there any possible way to run the Palm Pre app? Can I install ANYTHING to get on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Palm's mojo SDK](http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=page&id=1788&Itemid=21). It's a bundled VM that runs WebOS intended for development. If anything will let you do what you're asking, it will be that.

Comment: Can you link it please

Comment: http://bit.ly/g5AMXW